# Graphics libraries on Windows vs Linux

Tags: c#, linux, opentk, tao, mesa

Tao and OpenTK are two graphics libraries you can use with c# on Windows. Both not active, Tao last release is 2008 and OpenTK 2010.

But I see Mesa is active for Linux, so I wonder what should I use for my project. I need to develop CAD modeling app.

Should I go with Mesa and Linux? OpenGL changes a lot, and I need something up-to-date.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Mesa 3D is an implementation of the OpenGL library and specification; you write programs using the OpenGL API. OpenGL is probably your best bet in terms of features and cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: You mean not use libraries at all?

Comment: OpenGL is a library. The 'L' in OpenGL actually stands for 'library'. It's not like you're coding bare-metal with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for Windows only then there is DirectX of course.  The XNA framework is designed for Games I think but it may also be worth a quick look.

We have tools that use DirectX 2D as well as openGL.  I am using Piccolo which wraps both GDI+ and Direct2D.  Unfortunately that is no longer developed except for Java as open source